# Clojure error - trace error

Tags: exception, clojure, macros

I have a school assignment that has to be done by next week but here i am sitting and trying to solve a error problem which i really dont get why i am getting this?

According to my teacher i have to get this:

```
user> (def v (safe (/ 1 0))) 
user> v

ArithmeticException java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero
```

but what i am getting when doing this is:

```
java.io.File
user=> (def v (safe (/ 1 0)))
#'user/v
user=> v
#error {
 :cause "Divide by zero"
 :via
 [{:type java.lang.ArithmeticException
   :message "Divide by zero"
   :at [clojure.lang.Numbers divide "Numbers.java" 158]}]
 :trace
 [[clojure.lang.Numbers divide "Numbers.java" 158]
  [clojure.lang.Numbers divide "Numbers.java" 3808]
  [user$fn__17 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 30]
  [clojure.lang.AFn applyToHelper "AFn.java" 152]
  [clojure.lang.AFn applyTo "AFn.java" 144]
  [clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr eval "Compiler.java" 3623]
  [clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr eval "Compiler.java" 439]
  [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 6787]
  [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 6745]
  [clojure.core$eval invoke "core.clj" 3081]
  [clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7099$fn__7102 invoke "main.clj" 240]
  [clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7099 invoke "main.clj" 240]
  [clojure.main$repl$fn__7108 invoke "main.clj" 258]
  [clojure.main$repl doInvoke "main.clj" 258]
  [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 421]
  [clojure.main$repl_opt invoke "main.clj" 324]
  [clojure.main$main doInvoke "main.clj" 422]
  [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 397]
  [clojure.lang.Var invoke "Var.java" 375]
  [clojure.lang.AFn applyToHelper "AFn.java" 152]
  [clojure.lang.Var applyTo "Var.java" 700]
  [clojure.main main "main.java" 37]]}
```

Comment: since you use macros tag in your answer, can you post the body of the safe macro (or function) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it, just the format of the error is a bit different.

If you look at the `:via` key you'll see the `:type` key's value is `java.lang.ArithmeticException` and the `:message` key's value is `Divide by zero`

Put them together and you'll get `java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero`

This might be an issue with how you're running the REPL. I've never seen errors show up like this but I usually run the REPL with the leiningen command: `lein repl`